# embed git describe string in c++ binary

Tags: git, gcc, g++

How can I have the result of the git describe command embedded into my c++ binary so that I can access it at run time.

I know I can do something like this

```
g++ -DVERSION_NUMBER=2345
```

And then in my code I can do:

```
std::cout << VERSION_NUMBER << std::endl;
```

This is great but won't work if the value of version number is a string such as the output of the git describe command.

So is there way to do such a thing?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `g++ -DVERSION_NUMBER="\`git describe\`"` not work?

Comment: @Karl Bielefeldt No it does not. -D essentially defines a macro. A macro can evaluate to a numerical value, but if it contains a string then gcc tries to interpret that string as code which clearly won't work.

Comment: I see, the quotes are being removed by the shell.  It works for me if I escape the quotes, like `g++ -DVERSION_NUMBER="\"\`git describe\`\""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use automake, then you can use something like the following. I have been using it for a long time now, and it works fine to achieve what you are asking for.

In `Makefile.am`:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = git_info.h
EXTRA_DIST = echo_git_info.sh win_config.h

.
.
(main build recipes)
.
.

git_info.h: $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)
    echo_git_info.sh > git_info.h
```

In `echo_git_info.sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh

function echo_git_info {
    if [[ $(which git 2> /dev/null) ]]
    then
        local STATUS
        STATUS=$(git status 2>/dev/null)
        if [[ -z $STATUS ]]
        then
            return
        fi
        echo "`git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null | cut -b 12-`-`git log --pretty=format:\"%h\" -1`, "
        return
    fi
}

echo "// Auto-generated source/build information."
echo "#define GIT_SOURCE_DESC \"`echo_git_info``date`\""
```

The above will result in the the variable `GIT_SOURCE_DESC` being defined in the file `git_info.h`. Thus, in your `main.cpp` you can then:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ginkgo_info.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Source is: " << $GIT_SOURCE_DESC << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't use auto make but I can work this into my own make file. Not exactly what I was looking for but it will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do the same thing. I was able to get the `-D` flag to work just fine by using GNU Make's "shell" command like this:

Makefile:

```
VERSION=\"$(shell git describe)\"
CFLAGS=-DVERSION_NUMBER=$(VERSION) # etc
```

Then in the code I can reference the `VERSION_NUMBER` define with no problems, e.g.

test.c:

```
printf("Version string: %s\n", VERSION_NUMBER);
```

Comment: As @KarlBielefeldt said above, you may need to add escaped quotes, if the shell politely removes the first set for you.

Answer (score 2):

The [mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/VersioningWithMake) contains different possibilities how to gather this information with make.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe not the best but a way. You can write the string or anything else to the end of a binary file. One tutorial to achieve this is: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27979

The code is not c++ though. However you may port the examples to c++.