# Automatically include the current version number when compiling

Tags: c++, git, compilation, makefile, version

When using the source code, you can use the command `git describe` to get the current version number.

When using the binary, I added an option that allows users to pass in the `--version` flag to get that current version number:

```
if (argc >= 2) {
    if (argv[1] == "--version") {
        cout << "eval version v0.1-16-g74a9332";
    }
}
```

The problem is, that value `v0.1-16-g74a9332` is now hardcoded into my source. If I go off and change something somewhere else, I will have to increment this value every time I commit (which is just asking for merge conflicts!)

Moreover, the part `g74a9332` is the hash of the current commit. If I change this value in the source code, the hash of the commit changes.

Is there any way for me to, rather than hardcode the version number into the code, have c++ "know" the version number is `v0.1-16-g74a9332` when it compiles the binary?

Comment: I'm also using `make` for compiling, so answers that include that requirement are allowed, but I was hoping for some sort of compiler option or feature.

Comment: I am interested for a solution too.I usually include version as branch(major) /comments(minor).

Comment: @IQAndreas There is elementary bug in your code (and in @Oleg's otherwise correct solution). `argv[1] == "--version"` is a comparision of
two different `char *` pointers and will always fail. You need `std::string(argv[1]) == "--version"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [embed git describe string in c++ binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667216/embed-git-describe-string-in-c-binary)

Answer (score 2):

Generate the version number during building. For that, make an header `version.h` with the declaration of a global variable:

```
// add include guards
extern char const * const version_string;
```

To use the version string, include that header and refer to that global variable.

To keep it simple, create also a template for the corresponding definition, `version.c.template`:

```
char const * const version_string =
  "v0.1-COMMIT";
```

Then, add a rule to your makefile to build the corresponding source code file with string in the definition of that variable replaced with the actual commit number:

```
COMMIT := $(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)
.PHONY: version.c
version.c: version.c.template
    sed -e "s/COMMIT/$(COMMIT)/g" version.c.template > version.c
```

Include that `version.c` into compilation and linking process.

Of course you can scale that pretty much up to generate lots of information during build time.

*(I'm on a mobile and thus didn't test the above code)*

---

Since the compiler knows nothing about how you organise your source code, there's no such flag.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your code slightly

```
if (argc >= 2) {
    if (std::string(argv[1]) == "--version") {
        cout << MY_VERSION;
    }
}
```

Then, your Makefile must be:

```
result=$(shell git describe)

all:
    g++ -DMY_VERSION=\"$(result)\" -o main main.cpp

clean:
    rm -f main
```

Comment: `-DMY_VERSION` <- Is there supposed to be a space between `-D` and the variable name?

Comment: There is no space for my g++ (4.8.3). It is a working version. I've tried it.

Comment: [I guess you are right](http://homepages.gac.edu/~mc38/2001J/documentation/g++.html). Eeew... I read that as shorthand for `-D -M -Y -_ -V -E -R -S -I -O -N` etc. In fact, for that same reason, I have a personal vendetta against programs that use a single `-` for "multi-character" command-line arguments.

Comment: -DMY_VERSION=\"$(result)\"...............is equal to "#define MY_VERSION (result of git describe)" string in cpp file.  I don't understand why you don't like this suggestion.

Comment: @OlegGopkolov As others already pointed out `if (argv[1] == "--version")` won't work.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  It is easy to correct. The substance of question is "how to pass correctly to the program current version of source code".

Comment: @OlegGopkolov Then correct in your post please. We don't want future researchers hitting wrong code in answers.